# In a multilingual website should we provide the local language of the country even most of the people understand english there?

Tags: website-design, e-commerce, language, localization, users

In a multilingual website should we provide the local language of the country even if most of the people understand english there?

For example, In India. Most of the people who use computer and shop online understand more or less **English** but so many people don't know English but local languages **Hindi**

and our website's analytic shows that very few people are using **Hindi** version most of uses **English** so should i remove the **Hindi** version from website or it's better to keep it

Comment: Maybe you should attempt to make the Hindi language option more visible before you decide to remove it.

Comment: Depends on your target audience. Personally, I prefer English websites/forms to my native language ones, as terminology more familiar and standardized. If a substantial part of your audience feels better using Hindi (even if they do speak English), it might be good to provide it (only if cost-effective, of course).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what sort of users you are targeting and how much resources are avaliable.

As most of your users are highly educated and use English as their native language (by native language, I mean the language they are most comfortable with), then it is important that you focus on providing an English version of your website.

Are you planning to reach audiences/customers who speak Hindi? Are speakers of Hindi a potential customer/audience of what you are trying to say/sell? If so, then yes, you need to maintain a Hindi version of your site.

If you believe that a large portion customers/audiences you are targeting should prefer to use the Hindi version of your website, then you should do some testing to see why the Hindi version is not being utilized. Is it because the buttons/links to change languages are not prominent? Or is it that the Hindi content is not updated in a timely manner?

Conclusion:
It all boils down to your customers and audiences. If there is a demand for the Hindi version, and it allows you to reach your target audience and customers and you have the resources, then yes. If you don't have the resources and Hindi is not that important for your existing and potential customers, then provide a Hindi version on a best effort basis.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am in favor of keeping Hindi as on of the options since you might also be targeting a user base whose primary language is Hindi, you also need to realize that this kind of two or three language options works very well in countries where they have only two or three languages.

[image]

But, however, in a country like India, even though Hindi is the national language, you would run into pockets in a number of states where the regional language supersedes Hindi and you users might not find any use for the Hindi option and you might even antagonize people by not offering the site in their regional language.

That said, if you look at some of your analytical information and find that most of your traffic is coming from the Hindi belt, then you should go ahead and keep it as it allows users additional information and helps them relate to a site better (provided the site has been translated well).

Comment: for now only 5% people are using hindi compare to 95% OF english in India for my client's site. so we were thinking to remove the hindi option.

Comment: Yes but before you take the step, how much revenue do those 5 % contribute and do you anticipate more growth in that area

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's depend on the User if they give priority to content if it is also available in their local language.

Some great software supports an interface in Gujarati but not Hindi. The only reason for it is if HINDI guys have Hindi and English both interface and they use English first. Same thing if Gujarati guys choose Gujarati First if they have seen English and Gujarati both.

Most people are not interested in making the UI supported Hindi because Hindi user are mostly give priority to English whenever Chinese or Gujarati people are not.